# processing date and time information with php and sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, timestamp

Im building a program that grabs date and time information from tweets through the twitter api, my challenge right now is I need to figure out what the best plan is to go about storing a timestamp like this: Fri Jul 16 16:55:52 +0000 2010, into a mysql database and then after they are stored making an sql call to the database ordering them by the most recent date

Comment: A bit dirty, but [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) should work

Answer (score 1):

You will want to make the data type on your MySQL field a `DATETIME`. To insert you need to read the timestamp from Twitter into a PHP -readable timestamp with `strtotime()`, then convert it to the mysql format with the `date()` function.

For Example

```
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateFromTwitter));
```

Comment: It's simpler to take the timestamp produced by strtotime and pass it into a mysql `FROM_UNIXTIME(...)` during insert, saving two string formating/parsing stages.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the date into an valid mysql datetime

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("Fri Jul 16 16:55:52 +0000 2010"));
```

That then needs quoting and inserting into your table:

> $sql = "insert into tweets 
>   (tw,daydate) values ('$tweet',
>   '$date');"

Where daydate is a DATETIME field.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's strtotime() is surely a nice way of doing this but I've found issues working with strtotime() earlier. So perhaps you may like to do this only in MySQL, like:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING('Fri Jul 16 16:55:52 +0000 2010', 1, 20),
        ' ',
        SUBSTRING('Fri Jul 16 16:55:52 +0000 2010', -4)
    ),
'%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Y');
```

Please note that when doing so I've ignored the +0000 part of the time-stamp.

Hope this helps.